# How do I trigger a CSS @keyframe animation on scroll using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

1. Firstly, I'm having a little trouble animating these `box` elements on scroll using `jquery`. I want my `animation` to start when I scroll past 1/4 of a `section`.

   2. Secondly, my `box` divs used to be vertically centered, but after adding the `@keyframes` during the transition they are not centered anymore. If you remove the `animation-fill-mode: forwards` you can see how they go back up at the end of the transition.
   3. And a last question.. Can `jquery` be used to animate these two boxes when I start scrolling without having to write different code for each `sections`? I'm thinking that If I add some common classes to my `box` divs that should work, right?

Originally, in my `jquery` file I tried setting a `hidden` class with an `opacity:0` on the `box` divs and when I started scrolling that would change into a `showing` class with an `opacity:1`.. but that didn't go so well.

Other solutions found on YouTube weren't helpful either.. blending other people code with mine doesn't seem to work very well.

As you can see, there is no `jquery` code because It was a mess after my brain started messing with it and at one point I figured I should start fresh.

[Here](https://codepen.io/make96/pen/xjdbeR) is a link to my Codepen .

Jade

```
.landing-page
.section-one
  .box-one
.section-two
  .box-two
```

SASS

```
@mixin box()
  position: absolute
  width: 200px
  height: 200px
  background: black
.landing-page
  height: 100vh
  width: 100vw
  background: gray
.section-one
  position: relative
  height: 100vh
  width: 100vw
  background: lightblue
  .box-one
    @include box()
    top: 50%
    right: 10%
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
    animation-name: box-one-animation
    animation-duration: 2s
    animation-fill-mode: forwards
.section-two
  position: relative
  height: 100vh
  width: 100vw
  background: lightgreen
  .box-two
    @include box()
    top: 50%
    left: 10%
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
    animation-name: box-two-animation
    animation-duration: 2s
    animation-fill-mode: forwards

@keyframes box-one-animation
  0%
    transform: translateX(0)  
  100%
    transform: translateX(-50%)
@keyframes box-two-animation
  0%
    transform: translateX(0)  
  100%
    transform: translateX(50%)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will want to set up some event listeners for your scroll events this way you can trigger animations based on scrollPos or maybe an elements offset to top.

Here is the event listener:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll

```
var last_known_scroll_position = 0;
var ticking = false;

function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
  // do something with the scroll position
  console.log(scroll_pos);
  if(scroll_pos > 200){
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('box-one')[0].classList);
     document.getElementsByClassName('box-one')[0].classList.add('animate-me');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;
  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
      ticking = false;
    });
    ticking = true;
  }
});
```

Look at the `doSomething` function, this is where you can define your offsets or decide on your overall approach. For the css portion of this just pop a class on which refrences your animation to trigger the animations.

Pen is here: https://codepen.io/cidicles/pen/gzWwEz

---

There are a TON of great libraries that do these type of animations for you such as Scroll Magic or Skrollr but it's always funner to build your own :p.

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr
http://scrollmagic.io/